# Run 2 Laravel projects on NGINX on a single IP address

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a NGINX server where I want to run two Laravel projects on, using a single IP address, because I don't want to access it using domains. My current config looks like below, having tried 2 different approaches.

### First approach:

```
###
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /home/wishato/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        location /wishato {
        root /home/wishato-master/public;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }


# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
  try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
               #  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
```

### Second approach:

```
#
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name 94.182.191.81;

    location / {
        return 410;  # Default root of site won't exist.
   }

    location /proj1/ {

        alias /home/wishato/public;

                            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

       # any additional configuration for non-static content
    }

    location /proj2/ {
        alias /home/wishato-master/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        # any additional configuration for non-static content
    }

    location /proj3/ {
        alias /var/www/proj3;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        # any additional configuration for non-static content
    }




# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
   #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
  try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
               #  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
```

Unfortunately, none of the above worked for me. The second approach returns a [`410 Gone HTTP status code`](https://httpstatuses.com/410) on home page and a [`404 Not Found HTTP status code`](https://httpstatuses.com/404) on `proj1`. The first approach behaves as a link of that projects and again gives `404 Not Found`.

Comment: you exposed your public IP, is that okay?

Comment: yes and the setting for 1 project is just working fine for me

Comment: Also, choost one to be `default_server`, you can't have both be default at the same listen address. Btw, what is the path for this two config?

Comment: change the listen port number for the second virtual host if possible keep different server_name

Comment: Overall improved readability.

Comment: Small suggestion - your config files are poorly formatted, and include lots (50%?) of commented out stuff which is completely irrelevant to your question.  KISS - remove irrelevant stuff, format it nicely so it is easy to read.  The easier you make it to read/understand, the more likely you are to get help.